# While doing form validation on submit a form, the component is not updating in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I have a login in react,

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import { auth } from '../actions';


export const Login = () => {
   let history = useHistory();
   const dispatch = useDispatch();

   const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
   const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
   const [error, setError] = useState({email: '', password: ''});

   const validEmailRegex = RegExp(/^(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|. 
    (\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i);

   const handleChange = e => {
      e.persist();
      const { name, value } = e.target;
      let validationError = error;

      switch(name) {
        case 'email':
            setEmail(value);
            validationError.email = validEmailRegex.test(value) ? '' : 'Email is not valid';
            break;
        case 'password':
            setPassword(value)
            validationError.password = value.length < 8 ? 'Password must be 8 characters 
            long!': '';
            break;
        case 'submit':
            validationError.email = email.length < 1 ? 'Email is required'  : '';
            validationError.password = password.length < 1 ? 'Password is required'  : '';
        default:
            break;
      };
    setError(validationError);
    console.log('in change', error)
   };

const validateForm = (errors) => {
    let valid = true;
    Object.values(errors).forEach(
      // if we have an error string set valid to false
      (val) => val.length > 0 && (valid = false)
    );
    return valid;
};

const validate = () => {
    console.log('email,password', email, password);
    let validationError = error;
    if(!email){
        validationError.email = 'Email is required';
    }
    if(!password){
        validationError.password = 'Password is required';
    }
    setError(validationError);
    console.log('in validate',error)
};

const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    validate();
    console.log('error on submit', error);
    if(validateForm(error)) {
        dispatch(auth(email, password, true));
        history.replace('/home');
      }else{
        console.error('Invalid Form', error)
      }
};
return (
    <Fragment>
        <div className="w-full max-w-sm container mt-20 mx-auto">
            <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                <div className="w-full mb-5">
                    <label className="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" htmlFor="email">
                        Email
                    </label>
                    <input className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:text-gray-600" value={email} name='email' onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)} type="text" placeholder="Email" />
                    { error && <span style={{color: "red"}}>{error['email']}</span>}
                </div>
                <div className="w-full  mb-5">
                    <label className="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" htmlFor="password">
                        Password
                    </label>
                    <input className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:text-gray-600" value={password} name='password' onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)} type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                    { error && <span style={{color: "red"}}>{error['password']}</span>}
                </div>
                <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
                    <button className="mt-5 bg-green-400 w-full hover:bg-green-500 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">
                        Login
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div className="text-center mt-4 text-gray-500"><Link to='/'>Cancel</Link></div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </Fragment>
)
```

}

I have added field validation in onchange and in submit, the onchange validation is working correctly and showing erros. Validation on submit is also wokring fine, but still the component is not showing error when I try submit without any change in fields.

I am new to react, I dont know if this is the correct way to do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Follow this, it might help you to start with 
https://medium.com/@verdi/form-validation-in-react-2019-27bc9e39feac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put your code in a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/small-cherry-m6ej8?file=/src/Login.js:3232-3297) and it seems to work just fine. Note that i removed `className` properties and commented stuff that is not necessary to test your issue like `redux` imports.

Since I removed the `className` properties this could be an `CSS` issue, where your error `span` is actually rendered but not visible (check out the dev tools of your browser to see if the `span` is really not there).

Also I would recommend you to use a library if you use a lot of forms, since state handling + validation could get quite complicated and there are plenty solutions out there.
I wrote my own library - [react-fluent-form](https://www.react-fluent-form.com/) - feel free to check that out.

**EDIT**

The issue here is that when you update the `error` object using `setError` you always pass the same object reference:

```js
// this is not doing a copy
// validationError will have the same reference as error
let validationError = error;

// ...

// following line will not trigger a rerender
setError(validationError);
```

Since `error` and `validationError` have the same reference, `react` will asume no change has happened, thus it will cause [bail out of a state update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update). If you work with complex types (like objects or arrays) in state you always need to create a new reference instead of adapting the previous one:

```js
// this is an actual copy using the spread operator
// validationError will have different reference than error
let validationError = {...error};

// ...

// triggers rerender as expected
setError(validationError);
```

**EDIT 2**

I added a return value for `validate` to use the updated `validationError` object when calling `validateForm`.

```js
const validate = () => {
    //..
    let validationError = { ...error };

    // ...

    return validationError;
};

const onSubmit = e => {
    // ...
    const validationError = validate();

    if (validateForm(validationError)) {
    //...
    }
};
```

See the [updated code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-hermann-84z2z?file=/src/Login.js).

Comment: Its not working when I try to submit without any change in fields.

Comment: @LakshmipriyaMukundan sorry i completely overlooked that part.. i updated my answer

Comment: now the problem is the error variable is not updating, 'validationError' have the correct values. But setError is not working correctly I think.

Comment: @LakshmipriyaMukundan i added a new code sandbox with working code. I hope it helps